# Use InteropImage in WPF EmguCV

Tags: wpf, image-processing, emgucv

I want use EmguCV for image processing.I take camera preview with this code.

```
   CLEyeCameraImage kamera = new CLEyeCameraImage();
            kamera.ColorMode = CLEyeCameraColorMode.CLEYE_COLOR_PROCESSED;

            kamera.Device.Create(CLEyeCameraDevice.CameraUUID(i));


            kamera.Device.Start();
            kamera.Width = 500;
            kamera.Height = 500;
            InteropBitmap b = kamera.Device.BitmapSource;
            image.Source = b;
```

But i can't find how can i use this InteropBitmap in EmguCV for processing.How can i use interopbitmap in EmguCV ?

Answer (score 1):

You have to convert the `InteropBitmap` to a corresponding `Image<C,D>` object.
Since `InteropBitmap` is a `BitmapSource`, you could do this e.g. like that:

```
static Image<Bgr, byte> ConvertBitmapSourceToEmguImage(BitmapSource source)
{
    using (MemoryStream tempStream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        BitmapEncoder enc = new BmpBitmapEncoder();
        enc.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(source));
        enc.Save(tempStream);
        using (Bitmap tempBmp = new Bitmap(tempStream))
        {
            return new Image<Bgr, byte>(tempBmp);
        }
    }
}
```